# Importance of Friday prayers

Tags: salat, jumuah

I am working in a company and my boss is not allowing me for friday prayers event and not accepting my leaves on the same day. What can I do? help me in this regard in the light of the QURAN AND HADEETHS

Comment: change your job!

Comment: @Zia realize that Friday prayers are not mandatory. Meaning one is not *bound* to take part in it. So why change the job?

Comment: @BleedingFingers who told you that? please don't speak about what you don't know. Friday prayer is mandatory for men(fard ayn) see this link: http://quran.com/62/9 and this link: http://www.questionsonislam.com/question/it-fard-obligatory-perform-jumua-friday-prayer

Answer (score 4):

According to this ['fatwa'](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/210649), you should ask your boss to give you time for Friday prayer, And you can't skip Friday even for work, except if leaving work for prayer will cause to lose your job, or it will cause harm for your company etc. he didn't allow you to go to the prayer, you have an excuse to not go to Friday prayer. and must pray 'Duhur' instead.

> قال العلامة قليوبي وهو شافعي أثناء تعداده للأعذار في التخلف عن الجمعة
> قال: ومنه إجارة العين لمن لم يأذن له المستأجر، أو لزم فساد عمله.
> انتهى.  وقال صاحب الروض عند ذكره لتلك الأعذار: ويعذر بتركهما خائف من
> ضياع ماله، أو فواته، أو ضرر فيه كمن يخاف على ماله من لص ونحوه، أو له
> خبز في تنور يخاف عليه فساداً، أو له ضالة، أو آبق يرجو وجوده إذا أو
> يخاف فوته إن تركه ولو مستأجرا لحفظ بستان أو مال، أو ينضر في معيشة
> يحتاجها. انتهى.  قال النجدي في حاشيته على الروض معلقاً على الجملة
> الأخيرة: (ينضر في معيشة... إلخ): بأن عاقه حضور جمعة أو جماعة عن فعل ما
> هو محتاج لأجرته، كما لو كانت أجرته بقدر كفايته، أو هو وعياله، أو ثمنه،
> أو تحصيل تملك مال يحتاج إليه. انتهى.   وعلى المسلم بذل جميع الأسباب
> لإرضاء ربه وامتثال أمره، وأعظم أمره سبحانه وتعالى الصلاة؛ فإنها عماد
> الدين.  وَمَنْ يَتَّقِ اللَّهَ يَجْعَلْ لَهُ مَخْرَجًا * وَيَرْزُقْهُ
> مِنْ حَيْثُ لَا يَحْتَسِبُ وَمَنْ يَتَوَكَّلْ عَلَى اللَّهِ فَهُوَ
> حَسْبُهُ إِنَّ اللَّهَ بَالِغُ أَمْرِهِ قَدْ جَعَلَ اللَّهُ لِكُلِّ
> شَيْءٍ قَدْرًا {الطلاق:2-3}.

And for advice, try to leave your job to another one, so you can pray without harassment or annoyance.

> That is instructed to whoever should believe in Allah and the Last
> day. And whoever fears Allah - He will make for him a way out (2) And
> will provide for him from where he does not expect. And whoever relies
> upon Allah - then He is sufficient for him. Indeed, Allah will
> accomplish His purpose. Allah has already set for everything a
> [decreed] extent.(3)
> [Al-Talaq](http://quran.com/65)